# Android: Adding accessibility to a custom view

Tags: java, android, view, accessibility

I'm attempting to implement accessibility on a few custom views for an Android app.

I've condensed what is done in the [Google Authenticator app](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/source/browse/src/com/google/android/apps/authenticator/UserRowView.java?repo=android&name=0.91) with no luck:

```
public class CardView extends RelativeLayout {

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        event.setClassName(this.getClass().getName());
        event.setPackageName(this.getContext().getPackageName());
        event.getText().add("Card Test");
        return true;
    }
}
```

All TalkBack reports back is "Double-tap to select" when it's inside a ListView or ViewPager.

Does ViewPager override accessibility events?

What do I need to do in order to have TalkBack say "Card Test" inside ViewPagers and ListViews like I expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` and associated classes expect you to use the `onItemSelectedListener` instead of assigning an `onClickListener` to each View (and rightfully so).

Answer (score 2):

For current versions of Android, you need to set the content description of the view.

```
  myView.setContentDescription("Card Test");
```

Comment: Hi Alan, this looks like it's working in some cases, which is awesome! When it's put into a ListView or a ViewPager, the same "Double-tap to select" is reported. Do you know why ListViews and ViewPagers are preventing the custom View from reporting the content view?

Comment: Do you mean it's not speaking the content description when put into a ListView, or it's appending the "double-tap" hint and you'd prefer it not?

Comment: It's not speaking the content at all when put into a ListView. The reason is because the Views return false for isHoverable() when you set an OnClickListener. I'll just need to refactor to use onItemSelectedListener.

Comment: should we call setContentDescription insided customView  class or in an activity, because developer who use our view might forget to set accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

If incorporating alanv's suggestion, try to convince android system to read out the content description

by either

If(accessibilityModeIsEnabled())//custom method that checks context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE).isEnabled()

myView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER);

or AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED.

or requestFocus

Above should done when myView is visible. May be during onMesasure when width and height are both positive

If list view is still unable to do so, then try doing the above tricks on the first element of list view. Accessibility in Android varies devices to device and not one strategy fits all